# Acentuação tabela mysql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Bom dia.

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados e preciso fazer 2 selects nela:

Para a primeira busca estou usando essa e está retornando tudo que preciso:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_memoria WHERE memo_de IN ($words)
```

A segunda, eu preciso buscar de forma case-sensitive e accent-sensitive, só que não consigo fazer funcionar de forma alguma. Uma solução que achei me deu esse resultado:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_memoria WHERE CAST(memo_de AS CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1) COLLATE latin1_general_cs_ai IN ($words) AND status = 1
```

Mas ela não funciona quando a busca tem acento no meio.

Segue como está a estrutura da minha tabela:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: cara tem  ha ver com  a formatação tenta colocar  um collate utf8_general_ci na sua query

Comment: aqui pode achar algumas  informações uteis  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647080/accent-insensitive-search-query-in-mysql

Comment: Tentei essa: SELECT * FROM wp_memoria WHERE memo_de COLLATE utf8_general_ci IN ($words) AND status = 1. Sem sucesso ainda